# What is equivalent to defaultDisplay.getRealSize(point) in api 30?

Tags: android-studio, android-windowmanager

In api level 30 defaultDisplay is deprecated. So we need to use currentWindowMetrics. But there is no any getRealSize method in it. What will be equivalent to code:

```
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealSize(screenRealSize)
```

in API level 30?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is getBounds in windowMetrics, so we need to this method and set width and height separately to our variable like this:

```
    val screenRealSize = Point()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        val windowMetrics = activity.windowManager.currentWindowMetrics
        screenRealSize.x = windowMetrics.bounds.width()
        screenRealSize.y = windowMetrics.bounds.height()
    } else {
        activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay.getRealSize(screenRealSize)
    }
```